# Usage of CGAL::make_range

Tags: c++, boost, computational-geometry, cgal

I want to use the CGAL function `max_distance_to_triangle_mesh`. Its first argument is a range of points, and I fail to get it for two hours now. I think the code below is in the right way, but I tried to substitute `????` with numerous things, with no luck. I found only one example where the points are some pairs and `????` is obtained with `Property_map_to_unary_function`. I tried an identity function, with no luck.

```cpp
std::vector<Point> pts = ......;
double dist = PMP::max_distance_to_triangle_mesh(
  CGAL::make_range(
    boost::make_transform_iterator(
      pts.begin(), ????
    ),
    boost::make_transform_iterator(
      pts.end(), ????
    )
  ),
  mesh
);
```

I tried for example:

```cpp
auto get_pt = [](const Point &pt) {    
  return pt;    
};
```

and `????=&get_pt`. Then I got an error: "*no type named 'type'*" coming from **boost**.

Comment: Seems that you are struggling with `boost::make_transform_iterator` not `CGAL::make_range`. What transform do you actually want? Could you post the code for at least one of your attempts, and explain in more detail what the problems were (e.g. compiler errors or runtime errors). Please quote any error messages you see. Since you already spent two hours a few more minutes improving this question shouldn't be too much bother.

Comment: `&` is incorrect.

Comment: @john Thanks. I added one of my attempts. The transform I want is nothing but the identity.

Comment: @john You mean **&** at which place?

Comment: Then why use `boost::make_transform_iterator` at all? Just `CGAL::make_range(pts.begin(), pts.end())`

Comment: Here `&get_pt`.

Comment: @john The code you propose (**make_range(pts.begin(), pts.end())**) is my first attempt and it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to remove (and even to add) **&** at numerous places, no luck.

Comment: OK, then we're into the what does 'doesn't work' mean discussion again. Please quote code and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
PMP::max_distance_to_triangle_mesh<CGAL::Sequential_tag>(points, mesh)
```

***but*** this works when the kernel for `points` is `Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h` and that does not work if the kernel is `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h` (which is the one I used for three hours...)